# Does every curved spacetime have non-commuting generators of translations?

Tags: general-relativity, momentum, metric-tensor, curvature

If we define the generators of translations in a general spacetime to be $P_\mu$, is it true that in every curved spacetime we have $[P_\mu,P_\nu]\neq0$? Is it also true that for every spacetime where $[P_\mu,P_\nu]\neq0$ we have a Riemann curvature tensor which doesn't have all its elements equal to zero?

Comment: Translations are not a symmetry of a generic spacetime, so in curved spacetime, $P_\mu$ does not even exist. If a spacetime is asymptotically flat, then we can define a sort of translation generator that generates translations _at infinity_ (where the spacetime is flat). These translation generators do commute.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you define the translational generators $P_\mu$
as proportional to the covariant derivatives $\nabla_\mu$.

Then the commutativity of translational generators is indeed
equivalent to the nullness of Riemann's curvature tensor.

To see this recall the Ricci identity which relates the
commutator of covariant derivatives to Riemann's curvature tensor:
$$(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu)A_\alpha
 =R^\beta{}_{\alpha\mu\nu} A_\beta$$
It holds if the connection $\Gamma^\alpha{}_{\beta\mu}$ is torsionless.
See also [Riemann curvature tensor - Coordinate expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression).